# How can I run Spring Boot service from Android Studio?

Tags: android, spring-boot, android-studio

I am a newbie in Android development and I am currently facing issues to find any relevant reference for running a spring boot service on Android. What I could find was more related to Client-Server architecture. What If I do not want to use it as a Client and run the service locally ? Is there any reference or does someone has an idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn Retrofit.

Here is a link that can help you: 
         https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html